# Merge multiple massive DataFrames iteratively without running out of memory

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata, out-of-memory

I am trying to merge ~50 dataframes of (10M x 6) using the snippet bellow:

```
for i, df in enumerate(dfs, start=1):
    df.rename(columns={col:'{}_df{}'.format(col, i) for col in ("N_ALLELES", "N_CHR", "REF:freq", "ALT:freq")}, 
              inplace=True)
merge = functools.partial(pd.merge, on=['Chr.', 'Position'])
result = functools.reduce(merge, dfs)
```

The code runs perfectly fine for dfs of up to 8 million rows, but it crashes due to insufficient memory when I scale up to 10 million rows. I have reviewed other threads elaborating a similar problem.

Suggestions include indexing dfs prior to merging (which did not solve my problem) or using `numpy.memmap` which I am not quite sure how it fits my current approach?

Any suggestion would be really helpful!

Comment: You could try using [dask](https://dask.org/)

Comment: Have you tried `pd.concat` like `pd.concat([df.set_index(['Chr.', 'Position']) for df in dfs], axis=1)`?